# Unjustified downvotes

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, down-votes

I wish to communicate with a moderator concerning 4 injustified downvotes that was made on 2 of my questions and 2 of my answers.

#### These downvotes were done in a lapse of time of 1 minute and 12 seconds

at the following times:

20:57:55
20:58:07
20:58:29
20:59:07

#### These downvotes were done:

- The two first ones , on the only two questions I've ever asked
- The two later downvotes , on two questions that appeared to have been upvoted today and that were consequently at the top of the list of my upvoted answers, on the right side of the display.

So they were done on the immediately visible threads appearing in my user's page.

#### I also noticed a comment of mine has disappeared.

It was among the comments appended to this question:
[a single method call for many instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872389/a-single-method-call-for-many-instances?noredirect=1#comment31320543_20872389)

At 19:59 I did a question in a comment to the OP's question. It is still visible at this time. I was asking for more information on what the OP wanted to do.
I received two answers in comments, one of a user, and one of the OP, that were repeating exactly the same thing that is in the OP's question.
Then I did another comment saying I thought this answer was rather weird because the OP was supposing he was knowing perfectly to what amount of info it was sufficient to limit the question.

And now I notice that the two answering comments of the third user and of the OP , and my last comment too, have disappeared.

### Conclusion:

It is clear for me that these 4 downvotes done in a 1mn12secs burst have been made with retaliating intention.
The fact that the downvotes were done at this speed proves that they weren't done on the basis of the reading of the content of these questions and answers.

I wish to know if a moderator can examine who is the downvoter, to verify it is the OP user of the said question, and to judge and decide to remove these unjustified downvotes.

I don't care a lot about points, but I feel it is intolerable that any user may downvote like that, as if using a gun. That's not an attitude that fits with the desired functioning of SO, I think.
Moreover, it already happened something similar for some other answers of mine, 3 weeks ago, more or less, and I didn't say anything because I had another business to do, and also it is complicated for me to express in English.

But this time, **it is so evidently a bad manner that I can't let this pass** without asking some advice and explanation to a moderator.

Will I have the opportunity to speak with one ?

Comment: Not even moderators can associate votes with specific users.  Voting is all done anonymously.  Votes also cannot be removed by anyone, but the system can reverse lost rep if serial downvoting was done.

Comment: Thank you. Has a moderator the power to annul downvotes, even if he can't identify the downvoter , please ?

Comment: @Jamal What you wrote is wrong: _"moderators and/or developers may investigate the matter and disciplinary action may be taken against the users involved with the fraud."_ It is in the link given by Martjin : (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: @eyquem it's not wrong: "disciplinary action" is different from "undoing votes" which moderators cannot do

Comment: @MartjinPieters Thank you, great serial upvoted guy :)

Comment: @Pëkka I meant that if moderators can have some disciplinary action against a user, it is because they can identify the user. No ?

Comment: @eyquem ah, good point. I think moderators get a half-anonymized view, some information when an extreme amount of votes has gone from one user to another, but I do not know the details.

Comment: See tone of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704455/python-checking-type-of-variables/20708466#20708466.

Comment: @Rosinante What do you mean ?

Comment: Pretty hostile stuff. You could try being nicer.

Comment: Not hostile, just a litlle harsh, justified by the situation: a user posted an answer, he edited it two times because it was wrong, and in the end it is still wrong, and FIVE people upvoted it (where are their brain ? what is the value of reputation score after that ?) and on the top of that the OP accepted his answer, not realizing that the result of the proposed code is wrong. What will happen if he put this snippet in an important code ? I warned him on Dec 20, he came last on SO on Dec 25 and he didn't react. Is all this normal and requiring treacly wordings ? I'm stunned by all that

Comment: @Pëkka my understanding from reading something Brad Larson remarked in a comment once is that the mods can see patterns in voting that is still anonymized.  I interpret that to mean that they can't see who voted, but they can see the same user voted for a specific person and when (roughly).

Comment: @psubsee2003 To which comment of Brad Larson did you allude , please ?

Comment: @eyquem I'm going off of memory.  IIRC it was a comment on a meta post, which means it isn't really searchable.

Comment: @eyquem but if the downvotes weren't reversed automatically, it means they weren't serial or they didn't meant the criteria that the automatic script looks for.  Like Pekka said in his answer,  the only recourse is to email the community team via the contact us page, or flag one of your posts for moderator attention.  They will investigate and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Has a moderator the power to annul downvotes, even if he can't identify the downvoter , please ?

Read [Martijn's link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Short version: don't worry, the votes are likely to disappear automatically after 24 hours max.

If they don't, you can alert a moderator through flagging.

If they can't help either (I'm not sure whether they can), I would let the matter go - it's just a couple of points and most users become the victim of unfair downvoting at some point during their time on SO.

It's not nice, but it's not a big deal, either.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you. It isn't a very serious problem, but I am upset by the fact that anonymous guy or girl can downvote for psychological reasons, not for the content of the posts. I already let it pass several similar cases during the past months and years, but this time the case has something ridiculously evident.